# How to know what JavaScript functions are bound to an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know what JavaScript function is allocated to the events of an HTML element, an input, for example. I would like to check if it has any function bound to the onmouseover, or onclick, or any other event.

Comment: [VisualEvent](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/visual+event)

Comment: VisualEvent does not show anything. I think the function is not bound to the element using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain JavaScript, that information is not accessible.

So, your options:

- Some frameworks like you track event listeners provided you used their syntax to bind them (like jQuery).
- Some libraries will "rewrite" how event tracking works (like VisualEvent)
- Lastly, you can write your own wrapper around the add/removeEventListener functions, so that it tracks that information in addition to calling the native add/removeEventListener functions. Making sure it wraps all the possible ones, though, can be a challenge.

Comment: Used VisualEvent but didn't show anything on the element I'm debugging.

Comment: I did an alert of the .onclick prop and it showed me the function bound to the element. `alert(document.getElementById("...").onclick);`. You can add that as a sample to your last recommendation. This was not added using jQuery. I think that is the reason why VisualEvent does not show anything. Thanks, didn't think about it first.

Comment: `onclick` and any `on...` in plain JS is old-style (effectively deprecated) hard coded event handling, and very easy to check by simply running through the list of known names: `if(obj.onclick) { ... }`. However, in modern JS you don't have that option because we use `addEventListener("click",fn)` and `removeEventListener("click", fn)` for registering and dropping handlers.

Comment: Make sense, this is JavaScript wrote by another programmer and didn't know how it was implemented. Using addEventListener sounds good. But how to know what Event was bound to an element? alert(.onclick); isn't the right way? This addEventListener line might be on a really large JavaScript file and so hard to find.

Comment: it would be, so the very first question is "why do you need to know". If you have a good enough reason, you may want to either switch to a framework that does it for you, **or** write a shim that gets loaded as first script, and changes how addEventListener/removeEventListener works.

Comment: For debugging. I wanted to change how a button does some sort of things, but was not able to find what the function was being called on the click event.

Comment: For debugging you have tools for that already, namely your browser's dev tools. Good idea to read up on what they can do, and how they work!

Comment: I tried to look into the Inspector from Chrome, it doesn't have much information about the function bound to the element. How is the way to get the function name or content such as an alert(.onclick) does?

Comment: You are right, didn't realize of the file and line at the right of each listed event. If the JavaScript is minimized it doesn't show the code really good though, but I can format/beautify the code and do it again. Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Inspect your input box in Google Chrome browser, you can check the Event Listeners tab. You can also make use of timeline to track the firing events and effectively use DOM break points.

Comment: This is interesting. I checked Chrome and its event listener tab, but didn't really know how to use it. I added all the three breakpoints in there (sub-tree modifications, attr modifications, node removal) and when I click on the button, page is reloaded without breaking on any point. I guess because there is no breakpoint on page reload. Also, in the Event Listener tab, there is no info about the name of the function or where is it located.